# Classic ASP: Can the "Application" global object cause dead lock?

Tags: asp-classic, deadlock

In **classic ASP** there is a global object called **"Application"** that is accessed simultaniously by all sessions.

As the "Application" object is a shared resource, can it cause **dead locks?**

EDIT: If not, why does it has **lock** and **unlock** methods for? [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_application.asp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Deadlock** is different from normal **blocking**. Since pages are processed in different threads, if you want to prevent another request from modifying that shared resource, you use Lock, and to allow modification again, you use the Unlock method. The thing is, if you don't use those methods, *another request can change the value of an item in the application state, while you're relying on an old value*. Or two requests can try to modify it simultaneously and it might cause problems. Lock method causes a request to wait until the other request unlocks application; after that, it can continue.

Deadlock is a situation in which *thread A* **locks** *resource 1* and **waits** for *resource 2* to become available. At the same time *thread B*, which has **locked** *resource 2* needs to access *resource 1* (which is locked by *thread A*) to continue to work and be able to release the resource afterwards. In this situation, **none** of the threads can continue (one of them **has to be terminated** to allow continuation). This is a **deadlock**. Application.Lock will not cause deadlocks on its own if correctly used. But if it's not used correctly, it might cause deadlocks (when coupled with another shared resource that needs locking and deadlocks are not taken care of).

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely that the locking the ASP `Application` object will result in a deadlock lasting longer than the server script timeout setting.

The classic ASP `Application` object has Lock and Unlock for synchronizing changes to the Application objects. You can have multiple requests trying to make a change to the same value - without locking, making the change and then unlocking the change might be lost.

As simple example would be a counter of some sorts. Let's say your code does:

```
<%
Application("Count") = Application("Count") + 1
%>
```

If you have two simultaneous requests (req1 and req2) , you could "lose" a page hit - effectively a "missing update".

You can prevent this by locking the `Application` variable before updating it and unlocking it after the update:

```
<%
Application.Lock
Application("Count") = Application("Count") + 1
Application.Unlock
%>
```

If `Application` is locked while another request thread tries to access it, the thread will block until the lock is released or the script timeout is exceeded.

If you forget to Unlock a Lock it will be released automatically after the page is processed or after the script timeout is exceeded.

For more information, [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525184.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

No, it never blocks.

Answer (score 0):

A deadlock is a situation wherein two or more competing actions are waiting for the other to finish, and thus neither ever does.